# Distinct values from a column to use to parallelize a Pyspark dataframe to randomly select values

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am fairly new to Pyspark and I am running into some hiccups. Let's say I have two fields:

> ```
> | firstName | lastName |
> |-----------|----------|
> | Bill      | Apple    |
> | Mike      | Apple    |
> | Jeff      | Apple    |
> | Paul      | Apple    |
> | George    | Bowers   |
> | Kevin     | Bowers   |
> | Leon      | Bowers   |
> | Fred      | Bowers   |
> ```

My question is around how to randomly select 2 random rows for each distinct value of the last name? Like this:

> ```
> | firstName | lastName |
> |-----------|----------|
> | Jeff      | Apple    |
> | Bill      | Apple    |
> | Fred      | Bowers   |
> | Kevin     | Bowers   |
> ```

What I was thinking was to generate a list of the distinct last names and run through a for loop, but that obviously won't be recommended using Pyspark's framework. I would think that the use of parallel computing would be the recommended approach in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with some [analytic functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/analytic-function-concepts)' magic ✨

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

df.withColumn(
    "r", F.row_number().over(Window.partitionBy("lastName").orderBy(F.rand()))
).where(F.col("r") <= 2).drop("r").show()
+---------+--------+
|firstName|lastName|
+---------+--------+
|   Paul  |  Apple |
|   Bill  |  Apple |
|   Kevin |  Bowers|
|   Leon  |  Bowers|
+---------+--------+
```

If I re-run it for example :

```
+---------+--------+
|firstName|lastName|
+---------+--------+
|   Paul  |  Apple |
|   Mike  |  Apple |
|   Fred  |  Bowers|
|   Kevin |  Bowers|
+---------+--------+
```

Comment: Beautiful. Glad to know there are things like this in Pyspark. This executes as anticipated.